# float is not displaying the right format . looking for xxxxxx.xx

Tags: java, android, floating-point

```
float fRealEsate = 360000.00 * 0.04;
 Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Real Estate Brokerage Fee: " 
                     + fRealEsate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I need it to display 15600.00 but its displaying 15600.0

Comment: You should not use float for money.  money is fixed point not floating point.  consider storing dollars and cents as integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

```
String sRealEstate = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(fRealEstate);
```

And use the formatted string version in your Toast rather than the float directly.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 123456.123456f;
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat(".00");
System.out.println(nf.format(f));//123456.12
```

- [Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html)